# What is wrong with this scanf usage?

Tags: c, scanf

Here is a five digit number as input. I want this is program to calculate the sum of its digits and when I run program in dev compiler it stops responding and it give 255 as output for every five digit number.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n, a, b, c, d, e, f;
    printf("entre a no ");
    scanf("%d",n);

    a = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    b = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    c = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    d = n % 10;
    n = n / 10;
    e = n;
    f = (a + b + c + d + e);
    printf("sum of five digit=%d",f);
}
```

The expected output is the sum of the five digits.

But it always stops responding and it shows a dialog box asking me to close the program. After closing the program it always gives an output of 255, whatever the input number is.

Comment: In the call to `scanf`, you need to pass the address of the variable you want it to set.  Otherwise it has no way of modifying it.  So use `scanf("%d", &n);`  Also, when you're having trouble with something like this, it's a good idea to print the number, `n`, immediately after setting it to make sure you're getting what you expect.  If you had done so, you probably wouldn't have needed to post here.

Comment: You should check the value returned by `scanf()`; if it isn't 1, the input failed, either because of EOF or because the user didn't type a number. As Tom noted, it is a good idea to print the value that was 'read'. It would tell you there's something amiss. A good compiler (GCC, with appropriate warning options enabled: `gcc -Wall` will do for starters) will tell you about the type mismatch between the format string and the arguments passed to `scanf()`. Turn on the warnings; you can't afford not to. (Experts use them to make sure they haven't made silly mistakes; novices should use them too.)

Answer (score 6):

Change this statement

```
scanf("%d",n);
           ^^
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &n);
           ^^^^
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: @AkashElhance - Did you decide to skip "hello world" program ?  :)

Comment: @ryyker yeah i skip 'hello world" program.